# How to store stdout.channel.recv(1024).decode("utf-8") value in variable

Tags: python-2.7

I am using paramiko in python and when I running ssh.exec command, I have to use stdout.channel.recv(1024).decode("utf-8") to get formatted output. Here is sample code.

```
def runcmd(cmd):
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command (cmd)
    #stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command ('ls')
    # Wait for the command to terminate
    while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
        # Only print data if there is data to read in the channel
        if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
            rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
            if len(rl) > 0:
                # Print data from stdout
                print (stdout.channel.recv(1024).decode("utf-8"))
```

Now whatever o/p print by above command I have store in variable as I have to use this output to do some action.
When I am using output = runcmd(cmd) in main class. I am getting o/p as none. Any clue to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your runcmd function is only printing and not returning anything. You need to end the function with `return`.

Concretely:

```
def runcmd(cmd):
    out = ""
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command (cmd)
    #stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command ('ls')
    # Wait for the command to terminate
    while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
        # Only print data if there is data to read in the channel
        if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
            rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
            if len(rl) > 0:
            # Print data from stdout
                out = stdout.channel.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
                print out
                return out
```

Now that your function returns a string you can do:

```
output = runcmd(cmd)
```

Comment: I am able to find the issue. I have tried return statement yesterday s well, but I was facing some issue to display in correct format which I said in previous comment. When I am printing output using print (output)..it displaying correctly but when I tried to display with some message as print ("output is", output) , its not showing in correct format. Do you know what is the difference?

Comment: Did you try: `print u'Output is %s' % output` ?

Comment: cool. if it works you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark below the number of votes.

Comment: right underneath the downvote button for the answer.